# insert missing rows in df with dictionary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Hello I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'grade_1':['A','B','C'],
                        'grade_1_count': [19,28,32], 
                        'grade_2': ['pass','fail',np.nan],
                        'grade_2_count': [39,18, np.nan]})
```

whereby some grades as missing, and need to be inserted in to the grade_n column according to the values in this dictionary

```
grade_dict = {'grade_1':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
            'grade_2' : ['pass','fail','not present', 'borderline']}
```

and the corresponding row value in the _count column should be filled with np.nan
so the expected output is like this

```
expected_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'grade_1':['A','B','C','D','E','F'],
                        'grade_1_count': [19,28,32,0,0,0], 
                        'grade_2': ['pass','fail','not preset','borderline', np.nan, np.nan],
                        'grade_2_count': [39,18,0,0,np.nan,np.nan]})
```

so far I have this rather inelegant code that creates a column that includes all the correct categories for the grades, but i cannot reinsert it in to the dataframe, or fill the count columns with *zeros* (where the np.nans just reflect empty cells due to coercing columns with different lengths of rows) I hope that makes sense. any advice would be great. thanks

```
x=[]
for k, v in grade_dict.items():
    
    out = df[k].reindex(grade_dict[k], axis=0, fill_value=0)
    
    x = pd.concat([out], axis=1)
    x[k] = x.index
    x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
    df[k] = x.fillna(np.nan)
```

Comment: if there a match between "grade_1" and "grade_2" (e.g., "A"=="pass")?

Comment: @mozway no - all categories are discrete

Comment: so why does the first new row has D/borderline and the next E/NaN? The logic is unclear

Comment: the zeros reflect that there are no counts for the appended value from the dictionary and the nans are a product of combining columns with different lengths of rows if that makes sense

Comment: Answer working because sample data, if change their order it failed. There is no reindex/ match by categories in values in dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to merge on `grade_1` without updating the non-NaNs of `grade_2`, you can cast `grade_dict` into a df and then use `combine_first`:

```
print (df.set_index("grade_1").combine_first(pd.DataFrame(grade_dict.values(),
                                                          index=grade_dict.keys()).T.set_index("grade_1"))
         .fillna({"grade_1_count": 0}).reset_index())

  grade_1  grade_1_count      grade_2  grade_2_count
0       A           19.0         pass           39.0
1       B           28.0         fail           18.0
2       C           32.0  not present            NaN
3       D            0.0   borderline            NaN
4       E            0.0         None            NaN
5       F            0.0         None            NaN
```

Comment: I added a `set_index` to align on `grade_1`. Hope I understand it right.

Comment: it is necessary do for each key in dict.

Comment: so for `grade_2` if failed.

Comment: I think just need to set_index on grade_1? If set on both, grade_2 won't get updated as in the expected output.

Comment: @jezrael  I think OP just want to put 2 discrete tables of grade_1 and grade_2 together.  There is no need to match grade_1 A on grade_2 pass.  This is just the natural sequences the 2 discrete tables presented in the final outcome.  grade_1 will most probably always has grade in the sorted order of A, B, C, D.... F.   So, I think Henry's solution is fine.

Comment: @SeaBean - yes, but if order is change in `dict values` if match incorrect.

Comment: @jezrael  As you can see from the Q&A from the 2 comments in question, all categories are discrete.  No need to match as per OP.

Comment: @SeaBean - check `grade_dict = {'grade_1':['B','D','C','A','E','F'],
            'grade_2' : ['fail','pass','not present', 'borderline']}` this answer failed

Comment: @SeaBean - You are right if no `count` columns, then should be working (if order is not important). Bit now it wrongly assign values.

Comment: @jezrael   You are right!  I see what you mean now.  The 4th row of Grade_2 will become `pass` instead of `boderline`.  Thanks for clarification.

Comment: My understanding of this question is that as OP mentioned `whereby some grades as missing, and need to be inserted in to the grade_n column according to the values in this dictionary` instead of updating pre-existing `grade_2` values if its not NaN, but i could be wrong. I'll add that in the post to clarify.

Comment: @HenryYik This is really useful. Thanks so much. I am now trying to edit it so that for grade_2, the counts for not_present and borderline can be zero, and the 'None' values for both grade and grade count can be NaN - which i would prefer to do by matching the first part of the col name (i.e. grade_2). is it possible to add this in to the above command or i need to write a loop?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using two consecutive merges:

```
# set up combinations
from itertools import zip_longest
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(*grade_dict.values())), columns=grade_dict)

# merge
(df2.merge(df.filter(like='grade_1'),
           on='grade_1', how='left')
    .merge(df.filter(like='grade_2'),
           on='grade_2', how='left')
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
  grade_1  grade_1_count      grade_2  grade_2_count
0       A           19.0         pass           39.0
1       B           28.0         fail           18.0
2       C           32.0  not present            NaN
3       D            NaN   borderline            NaN
4       E            NaN         None            NaN
5       F            NaN         None            NaN
```

##### multiple merges:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip_longest(*grade_dict.values())), columns=grade_dict)
for col in grade_dict:
    df2 = df2.merge(df.filter(like=col),
                    on=col, how='left')
df2
```

Comment: this is great. but what about if there are say 20 or so columns (or pairs of grades and counts) - is there a way to merge them without specifying the col names in each merge command?